# Database project needs to create new tables, access old tables

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm trying to visualize how this will be set up... I need my VB.NET application to read year 2013 values (Year, Employee, and Annual Performance Score) from a CSV file and write them to an Access DB. This DB is linked to my VB.NET project using a dataset. No problem, I have done this before.

However, when the new performance scores are available in year 2014 and the user opens this application, I need it to create a new, identical Access DB (with no records) for 2014 and fill those values from the new CSV. Then I need the user to be able to select a year and have VB.NET connect to the appropriate DB so the user can look up historic values.

The key here is not the CSV read or the DB write, it is the creation of the new year's DB and the dynamic re-link of the dataset to the new DB.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this approach:

- manually create a copy of your 2013 database, and remove all records (this will become your database template)
- on January 1st, copy this template; the copy is your DB for 2014
- repeat ad infinitum

Comment: The issue here is that this needs to all be automatic for the user. Another person suggested I just create different tables within the same DB for the new year. I think I like that idea, but how do you take a newly created table in VB.NET and apply it to the Access DB?

Comment: You could setup a scheduled task that runs on January 1st at 01:00 and renames current.db to 2013.db and copies the empty template to current.db.